# Michael Hartl Ruby Tutorial SQL Exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

So I'm doing the Michael Hartl rails tutorial and have it completely done. It is running with two errors, however.

It's the same error twice, and is as follows:

```
Error:
PasswordResetsTest#test_password_resets:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: reset_sent_at: UPDATE "users" SET "reset_digest" = '$2a$04$W0ZosPrPZYt.uZi.onBQsOI/SEAYdCkNbXWKWtX.64mkkuGohToha', "reset_sent_at" = '2017-08-01 22:46:32.972718' WHERE "users"."id" = ?
    app/models/user.rb:82:in `create_reset_digest'
    app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:12:in `create'
    test/integration/password_resets_test.rb:18:in `block in <class:PasswordResetsTest>'
```

As far as I know the following pages are the only relevant pages to the issue, but I could be wrong. So feel free to yell at me if that's the case :)

This is the schema file

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170622040432) do

  create_table "microposts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "picture"
    t.index ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_microposts_on_user_id_and_created_at"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_microposts_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "relationships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "follower_id"
    t.integer  "followed_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.index ["followed_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_followed_id"
    t.index ["follower_id", "followed_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_follower_id_and_followed_id", unique: true
    t.index ["follower_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_follower_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",                        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                        null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_digest"
    t.boolean  "admin",             default: false
    t.string   "activation_digest"
    t.boolean  "activated",         default: false
    t.datetime "activated_at"
    t.string   "reset_digest"
    t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  end

end
```

This is the Password Reset Test file

```
require 'test_helper'

class PasswordResetsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "password resets" do
    get new_password_reset_path
    assert_template 'password_resets/new'
    # Invalid email
    post password_resets_path, params: { password_reset: { email: "" } }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_template 'password_resets/new'
    # Valid email
    post password_resets_path,
         params: { password_reset: { email: @user.email } }
    assert_not_equal @user.reset_digest, @user.reload.reset_digest
    assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Password reset form
    user = assigns(:user)
    # Wrong email
    get edit_password_reset_path(user.reset_token, email: "")
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Inactive user
    user.toggle!(:activated)
    get edit_password_reset_path(user.reset_token, email: user.email)
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    user.toggle!(:activated)
    # Right email, wrong token
    get edit_password_reset_path('wrong token', email: user.email)
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Right email, right token
    get edit_password_reset_path(user.reset_token, email: user.email)
    assert_template 'password_resets/edit'
    assert_select "input[name=email][type=hidden][value=?]", user.email
    # Invalid password & confirmation
    patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
          params: { email: user.email,
                    user: { password:              "foobaz",
                            password_confirmation: "barquux" } }
    assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
    # Empty password
    patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
          params: { email: user.email,
                    user: { password:              "",
                            password_confirmation: "" } }
    assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
    # Valid password & confirmation
    patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
          params: { email: user.email,
                    user: { password:              "foobaz",
                            password_confirmation: "foobaz" } }
    assert is_logged_in?
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to user
  end

  test "expired token" do
    get new_password_reset_path
    post password_resets_path,
         params: { password_reset: { email: @user.email } }

    @user = assigns(:user)
    @user.update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, 3.hours.ago)
    patch password_reset_path(@user.reset_token),
          params: { email: @user.email,
                    user: { password:              "foobar",
                            password_confirmation: "foobar" } }
    assert_response :redirect
    follow_redirect!
    assert_match /expired/i, response.body
  end

end
```

And this is the Password Reset Controller

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_user,         only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :valid_user,       only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :check_expiration, only: [:edit, :update]    # Case (1)

  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_reset][:email].downcase)
    if @user
      @user.create_reset_digest
      @user.send_password_reset_email
      flash[:info] = "Email sent with password reset instructions"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Email address not found"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if params[:user][:password].empty?
      @user.errors.add(:password, "can't be empty")
      render 'edit'
    elsif @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      log_in @user
      @user.update_attribute(:reset_digest, nil)
      flash[:success] = "Password has been reset."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end


  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Before filters

    def get_user
      @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    end

    # Confirms a valid user.
    def valid_user
      unless (@user && @user.activated? &&
              @user.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id]))
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end

    # Checks expiration of reset token.
    def check_expiration
      if @user.password_reset_expired?
        flash[:danger] = "Password reset has expired."
        redirect_to new_password_reset_url
      end
    end
end
```

As you can see, all the referenced columns are present. I suppose the problem could be it's looking for a column in the wrong table, and therefore not finding it. I haven't found evidence to that claim, but it would logically solve the problem

Also, like I said above, I've followed this tutorial to it's completion. So the only thing that might be missing is an exercise I didn't see, but other than that if something is missing that could be a problem.

Like I said before if I've left anything out you guys need feel free to yell at me. I can't find out why it throws this exception, hopefully you guys can help

Thanks

Comment: Have you run your migrations and test prepared the database for the spec? `bundle exec rake db:migrate db:test:prepare`

Comment: Db:test:prepare did the trick. I didn't actually know that command existed. Thanks so much :)

Comment: cool, glad it helped - always run it after every migration to keep development and test synced

Comment: Not sure which version of Rails you are running, but you shouldn't really need to run `db:test:prepare` anymore. You probably didn't know that it existed because it has been deprecated.

Comment: 5.0.(3 or 4) I can't remember which. I had literally never had to run anything other than reset or migrate so I don't doubt that